# Excessão trhow travando o servidor

Tags: node.js, prisma, throw

Estou criando uma api com nest js / node / typeorm/ prisma; no momento estou configurando as requisições para 'get' de usuário. Usando o o imnsonia para testar.  Por alguma razão, todas as minhas excessões throw do meu método create estão dando erro - ao invés de retornarem a mensagem que eu configurei na trhow, como uma resposta no cliente imnsonia, a throw na verdade está derrubando meu servidor e travando minha aplicação. O erro, quando testo qulaquer ums das trhows do meu método create, é sempre semelhante ao que desscreverei abaixo.

Por exemplo, imagine que eu requiro um post create() propositalmente sem email, para que a throw me retorne um erro com a mensagem "Email is required!". O certo seria o cliente imnsonia receber como resposta um objeto que contivesse o número do erro e a mensagem que eu configurei ("Email is required!")  Ao invés disso, ele retorna "No body returned for response" no imnsonia, e no meu terminal o node para de servir, por que deu erro ao executar a trhow. Segue a descrição do erro que sai no terminal:

```
C:\Users\Mário\Desktop\HCODE-NODEJS\FASE01\05_CONFIGURANDO_APP_PRINCIPAL\ferrari-api\src\user\user.service.ts:76
    throw new BadRequestException('Email is required')
          ^ 
BadRequestException: Email is required
at UserService.create (C:\Users\Mário\Desktop\HCODE-NODEJS\FASE01\05_CONFIGURANDO_APP_PRINCIPAL\ferrari-api\src\user\user.service.ts:76:15)
at AuthController.register (C:\Users\Mário\Desktop\HCODE-NODEJS\FASE01\05_CONFIGURANDO_APP_PRINCIPAL\ferrari-api\src\auth\auth.controller.ts:44:22)
at C:\Users\Mário\Desktop\HCODE-NODEJS\FASE01\05_CONFIGURANDO_APP_PRINCIPAL\ferrari-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at C:\Users\Mário\Desktop\HCODE-NODEJS\FASE01\05_CONFIGURANDO_APP_PRINCIPAL\ferrari-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
at C:\Users\Mário\Desktop\HCODE-NODEJS\FASE01\05_CONFIGURANDO_APP_PRINCIPAL\ferrari-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

O estranho é que eu já tentei trocar o código da user.service pelo de um colega que também está fazendo o mesmo projeto, e o dele está funcionando. Quando fizemos a troca, para ver o que acontecia, o meu código funcionou normal no projeto dele, e o dele não funcionou no meu projeto (????)

Vou deixar abaixo o código do meu método create() que está na user.service, e também o link do rep no meu github, onde já deixei uma branch indicando o erro. Uma outra observação importante é que curiosamente as outras trhows do meu user,service funcionam normalmente, apenas as do meu método create não estão funcionando.

```
  async create ({
     name,
     email,
     password,
     birthAt,
     phone,
     document
  }:{name:string;
     email:string;
     password: string;
     birthAt?: Date;
     phone?:string;
     document?: string}) {

  if(!name){
    throw new BadRequestException('Name is required')
  }
  if(!email){
    throw new BadRequestException('Email is required')
  }
  if(!password){
    throw new BadRequestException('Password is required')
  }

  if(birthAt && birthAt.toString().toLowerCase() === 'invalid date') {
    throw new BadRequestException('birth Date is invalid!')
  }


  let user = null
  try {
    user = await this.getByEmail(email)
     
  } catch (e) {

  }

  if(user) {
    throw new BadRequestException("Email already exists!")
  } 

  
  return this.prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        person: {
          create: {
            name,
            birthAt,
            document,
            phone
          },
        },
        email,
        password,
      },
      include: {
        person: true
      }
    })    



  }
```

Agradeço de verdade qualquer ideia ou ajuda, tenho uma prova em 3 dias e dependo desse código rodando  :-0

Repositório no github: https://github.com/yurikgs/estudo_API_hcode_Com_nest.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito procurar, e com ajuda de alguns colegas, descobri que faltava um return no código da minha auth.controller, que é quem quem chamava a UserService.create() - no caso era exatamente o return que chamava o create que estava faltando, então ele até executava normalmente o método, mas não retornava nada... problema resolvido.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).